# How to modify nagios notificatios message to include last octet of the ip address

Tags: nagios

Does any one know where to look to modify the notifications that nagios send to have only last  2 octet of the ip 
lets say my ip is 192.168. 1.1

I wanted to have x.x.1.1  os it can be replaced with xs or just view the last 2 octets

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `notify-host-by-email` or `notify-service-by-email` command definitions in `/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg` for supporting your format.

Answer (score 0):

youd need to modify

/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg

eg

```
 'notify-host-by-email' command definition
define command{
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

perhaps modify that a bit to pipe hostaddress thru the cut command and get just the octets you want... 
eg 
[like in this example](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/112831-trim-last-octate-ip-address-using-bash-script.html)

Comment: This is not always in /etc/nagio3....it depends on your installation.

Comment: @mike  looking at the link they had the script using cut to replace the last octet  how do  I do that for the first two I tried different combination and googled it but I couldtnt find any references on that not good in programming with shell your help is appreciated  > cat test.sh
> ip=$1
> baseip=`echo $ip | cut -d"." -f1-3`
> echo $baseip".0"
> ./test.sh 192.168.133.14  = 192.168.133.0